# Is it possible to design Business Processes with Intalio Designer or others and deploy them with WSO2 BPS?

Tags: wso2, bpel, bpmn, business-process

I'm a newcomer in BPM world. The docs and articles in Internet show that WSO2 BPS 2.x is supposed to execute processes complying WS-BPEL, WS-Human Tasks & BPEL4People. BPMN 2.0 seems to fill the gap to translate between notation and executable languages defining how notations have to be translated.

Intalio BPM Server and WSO2 BPS are both based on Apache ODE. So my question is:

Is it feasible to design processes (human & business) with Intalio Designer and execute them using WSO2 BPS? Is anyone using this config? What are the cons?

Comment: More than a year after this post, we are using: Activiti a workflow engine with BPMN 2.0 support. As modeller we use Activiti Designer and Yaoquiang (excellent tool!).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both Intalio BPM Server and WSO2 BPS are based on Apache ODE.

So you can design with Intalio designer and deploy them to WSO2 BPS.

As long as the outcome of the designer is standard BPEL, and because of the fact that Apache ODE is in execution, there is little room for any major problems. So there are no cons, per say!

The pros is that, Intalio designer is easy to use and state of the art. So the designing task can be done easily with the designer. WSO2 Carbon Studio is an alternative, and I hope it will be as easy to use as the Intalio designer in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want do that ? You can directly execute the process in Intalio BPMS itself.

Comment: Because I like WSO2 product policy, documentation, framework, management interfaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Carbon Studio 1.0.4 has complete BPEL editing support. You can use Carbon Studio plugin with Eclipse Galileo for BPEL process modeling for WSO2 Business Process Server.You can find video on BPEL process modeling at http://wso2.org/premium/webinars/developing-bpel-processes-using-wso2-carbon-studio.